# Build the Azure IoT sdk for arduino yun on ubuntu x86

Tags: azure, ubuntu, iot, arduino-yun, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to build Azure IoT sdk for arduino yun on ubuntu 14.04 and getting the following error while running .\build.sh script.

> azure-c-shared-utility/c/adapters/socketio_berkeley.c: In function 'socketio_open':
>   azure-c-shared-utility/c/adapters/socketio_berkeley.c:228:24: error: variable 'addrHint' has initializer but incomplete type

I am following the instructions list [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/doc/get_started/openwrt-arduino-yun-c.md). Does anyone know how to get around this error and get successful build?

I guess this shouldn't be a problem but want to mention that I am using Ubuntu installed in virtualbox on windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

build succeeded after upgrading   gcc to 4.9 and cmake to 3.2.  Found instruction at the following location.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/c/doc/devbox_setup.md#set-up-a-linux-development-environment

[How do I use the latest gcc 4.9 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[How to install cmake 3.2 on ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610291/how-to-install-cmake-3-2-on-ubuntu-14-04)